# Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from. remote: Referenced from: /tmp/build_b7392388/client/.eslintrc.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, client-server, eslint

I get this error when I try to deploy to Heroku :

> [eslint] Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from.
> remote: Referenced from: /tmp/build_b7392388/client/.eslintrc.json

I have a client-server architecture that looks like this:

[image]

And in detail it looks like this:

[image]

Client part contains .eslintrc.json but the server part (root folder) does not.

Here is package.json from server (root folder):

```
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "name": "emoteco_nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.5"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "applicationinsights": "^2.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.7",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "gm": "^1.23.1",
    "image-data-uri": "^2.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.2.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "node-html-to-image": "^3.2.4",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.7",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.52.1"
  }
}
```

Here is package.json from client (sub folder):

```
{
  "name": "emotecoapp",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Creative Tim",
  "license": "See license in https://www.creative-tim.com/license",
  "description": "Otis Kit PRO by Creative Tim",
  "homepage": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-otis-kit-pro/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-otis-kit-pro.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14 || 15 || 16",
    "npm": ">=6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.6.2",
    "@mui/material": "5.6.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "5.6.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "chroma-js": "2.4.2",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.13",
    "onnxjs": "^0.1.8",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "5.1.0",
    "react-countup": "6.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-flatpickr": "3.10.11",
    "react-native-pytorch-core": "^0.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "15.5.0",
    "react-webcam": "^7.0.1",
    "rellax": "1.12.1",
    "swiper": "7.3.4",
    "typed.js": "2.0.12",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.5.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

I have tried several solutions like:

1.

> npm install -g install-peerdeps
>
> install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
>
> install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb-base

It didn't work.

2.
I also tried to change the setting.json of the VScode workspace like this:

```
{
    "eslint.workingDirectories": [
        "./client"
      ]
}
```

It didn't work as well

I have tried most of suggested solutions on internet but nothing works on my case.

Do you have any idea how I can solve my issue?